# Unable to find tag and regular expression in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Given an example html string

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="td" height="25">Upstream Power</td>
<td class="td">25.2 dBmV</td>
<td class="td">49.2 dBmV</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can find text using:

```
soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Power"))
```

But to find the entire tag doesn't find anything.  What am I missing?

```
soup.find_all("td",text=re.compile("Power"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BS3, the method is [`findAll`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) not `find_all`:

```
>>> markup = '''<table>
... <tr>
... <td class="td" height="25">Upstream Power</td>
... <td class="td">25.2 dBmV</td>
... <td class="td">49.2 dBmV</td>
... </tr>
... </table>'''
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup = bs(markup)
>>> import re
>>> soup.findAll(text=re.compile('Power'))
... [u'Upstream Power']
```

---

Edit:  I see that the method [was renamed in BS4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It seems to work OK for me:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup = bs(markup)
>>> soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Power'))
... [u'Upstream Power']
```

---

Edit2:  To make navigating the parse tree easier, you can [use tag names](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names):

```
>>> soup.td.find_all(text=re.compile('Power'))
... [u'Upstream Power']
```

Comment: yes soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Power')) works for me also, but why doesn't soup.find_all("td",text=re.compile("Power")).  I need something like this because I want to traverse the tree from this point.

Comment: @CptanPanic: Ah, I missed that. I edited answer with a better way to get just the elements you want.